# Inheriting from Frame and mainloop on Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

In the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) (Python 3.7) there's the following example and I'm trying to understand how the code works. From original code I added some comments.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)  # Initialize the tk.Frame class
        self.master = master  # Is it necessary?
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")


def main():
    # Instance of the root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    # Instance of the main frame
    app = Application(master=root)
    # Infinite loop used to run the application
    app.mainloop()  # mainloop() on tk.Tk() instance (root) or tk.Frame() instance (app)?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've two questions about this code:

- After initialize *tk.Frame* class with `super().__init__(master)` in *Application* class, which inherits *tk.Frame*, `self.master` already contains reference to the root window. I verified that by printing `id(self.master)` before and after. So, is `self.master = master` necessary? Why was it added?
- The *mainloop()* method is added to *app* instance of *Application* class, which inherits *tk.Frame*. But I could add the *mainloop()* method to *root* instance of *tk.Tk* class. The application works in both cases. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`self.master = master` is not necessary for inheriting from tkinter classes. It is redundant in this case. Also you do not need master in super. Simply do `super().__init__()` will work here.

You should not use a geometry manager from within the frame to place itself on the parent container. Instead call it from outside the class. Say you need to change it from `pack()` to `grid()` you would have to change it in the class instead of simply updated its placement in the main code.

Your mainloop should be referencing the root instance.

I would pass all the initial parameters when creating the button. Its just adding more lines of code to update each parameter separately.

One last thing. If you are going to be editing a variable/widget later in your code then use `self.` prefix to make it a class attribute but if not there is no reason to use `self.` so we can remove them from the buttons.

Reworked code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Button(self, text="Hello World\n(click me)", command=self.say_hi).pack(side="top")
        tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy).pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Application().pack()
    # app = MaxiTeam(root) # not sure what this is unless you meant Application?
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: _"Also you do not need master in super."_ I think that's bad advice. While it's not necessary in this specific case since the default is to put the frame in the root window, it's not true if you expect your class to be put inside anything other than root. The zen of python says explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have never had to do anything other than `super().__init__()` within classes that inherit from a tkinter widget. Typically I do not write any other inherited classes so I guess I have not had to deal with any case where it mattered. Can you point out an example where it is important? Also a largely accepted [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/7475225)  states"you can just say `super().__init__()` instead of `super(ChildB, self).__init__()` which IMO is quite a bit nicer." I admit I have not dug deeper as it appeared to be the accepted method.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I don't understand how _Application_ class knows who is the root window without passing the _root_ instance

Comment: @Mike-SMT: in this example, in `main`, create a frame and then put `Application` inside of the frame rather than in root. eg `lf = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Something");  Application(lf)`. If you don't pass `master` into `super.__init()`, the application will not be inside the labelframe.

Comment: With `super` you don't need to specify the subclass, but you do need to pass on any configuration options, otherwise the base class has no way of seeing the configuration options.